# Highest unique prime factors in range

Tags: ruby, math, prime-factoring

I am trying to scale a solution I have to a Hackerrank *practice* question.

The question, in summary is, find the max number of prime factors in a range.

For `1..500` it's `4 for 210 -> 2(1), 3(1), 5(1), 7(1)`
For `1..5000` it's `5 for 2310 -> 2(1), 3(1), 5(1), 7(1), 11(1)`
For `1..50000` it's `6 for 30030 -> 2(1), 3(1), 5(1), 7(1), 11(1), 13(1)`

This is my solution

```
require 'prime'
max = 0
for d in 1..n
    pfs = d.prime_division.count
    max = pfs if pfs > max
end
puts max
```

This takes forever for `n = 10000000000`.

I may be looking at the solution from the wrong perspective.
How do I scale this solution?

Comment: Does it require you to find the max number of *unique* prime factors in a range? Because your code seems to do just that.

Comment: Yes. And that's what my code does. But it does not scale, @Coolness

Comment: Right, it's just that you might want to edit that in (in case someone looks at this in the future), because the non-unique problem is a different one :)

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: With all due respect : You answered this one after I completed my reply. The structure of your code is very similar to my last method (I surely don't mean to imply you copied it : Just that's it doesn't add much value after the question has been answered), and your method actually doesn't return the desired output. So please don't feel bad : you'll get your "revenge" on another question.

Comment: @Eric, I'm not suggesting that my answer be selected. I often chide askers for quick-draw selections, regardless of whether I've submitted an answer, am working on one, have no intention of answering or have submitted the answer that has been selected (in which case I usually suggest the greenie be removed)! I usually point out the downsides of a quick selection (it may discourage other answers and ,imo, is disrespectful to those still woking on answers) and ask if there is any argument for a rapid selection.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

The numbers in your example are just the products of the first Primes, which actually makes sense if you want to minimize the product while maximizing the number of factors.

See this integer [sequence](http://oeis.org/A002110) for more information :

> a(n) is the least number N with n distinct prime factors

#### Code

```
require 'prime'

n = 50000

p (1..n).find{|i| Prime.take(i+1).inject(:*) > n}
#=> 6
```

With `n = 10000000000` :

```
p (1..n).find{|i| Prime.take(i+1).inject(:*) > n}
#=> 10
```

#### Explanation

It calculates the product of the first `i+1` primes until it is greater than n. In this case, `i` is the desired output.

Note that `i` is always smaller than n, so searching the Range `(1..n)` will be more than enough. `find` stops the search as soon as block returns a truthy value, so it doesn't matter if `range.max` is `n` or even `Float::INFINITY`.

It isn't really efficient to calculate the product for each `i`, but the solution is found so fast it probably doesn't matter : The product of the first k primes grows faster than `k!`, so less than `O(Γ**-1(n))` steps are needed.

#### For which number?

If you want to know for which number it is :

```
p Prime.inject { |product, prime|
  new_product = prime * product
  break product if new_product > n
  new_product
}
#=> 6469693230
```

or just :

```
p Prime.take(10).inject(:*)
#=> 6469693230
```

Comment: This is genius. I thought I knew Enumerable. Teach me, master

Comment: Great solution. I'm curious, how does `(1..n).find()` work so fast? Is it optimized to binary search seeing as the interval is sorted? I'm presuming `(1..n)` doesn't allocate an array since that would take too much time here. Does it call `Range#bsearch`?

Comment: @Coolness: I updated the answer. `(1..n).find` begins with 1, and iterates until the block is truthy. This happens really fast because product of `m` first primes grows faster than exponentially. The range max actually doesn't matter at all, and no array is created. See `(1..Float::INFINITY).find{|x| x > 100}`

Comment: `n = Float::INFINITY` would be a wee problem. Note you don't have to take the first `i+1` primes each time. Just multiply the product of the first `i` by the next one. Granted, you wouldn't be saving much time.

Comment: I never talked about `n = Float::INFINITY`

Comment: @CarySwoveland : I updated the answer. The time complexity is so low that I'd much rather have a nice and readable one-liner than trying to optimize for peanuts. No. `n != range.max`, but `range.max` can be defined to be `n`. EDIT: You got it.

Comment: To  make it clearer I would suggest `1.step.find {...}`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I've never seen `1.step`, interesting! I don't find it clearer though.

Comment: I prefer `1.step` or the less attractive `1..Float::INFINITY` to `1..n` because latter requires the reader to ask "why `n`?". This is evidenced by the asker's first comment above. If the range were infinite it would be obvious that the block  would just iterate away until it found `true`. I think it was Ruby v2.1 when the `limit` argument for [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step) became optional.

Comment: In that case, the user probably would have asked : "what is `1.step.find`?" :)

Comment: I hope so! Then they would have learned something new about Ruby.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132949/discussion-between-eric-duminil-and-cary-swoveland).

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of distinct primes between `2` and `n` is `m` such that `P(m) <= n < P(m+1)`, where `P(m) = p`<sub>`1`</sub>`*p`<sub>`2`</sub>`*...*p`<sub>`m`</sub>, `p`<sub>`i`</sub> being the `i`th largest prime. The proof (by contradiction) is simple. Suppose `q`<sub>`1`</sub>`*q`<sub>`2`</sub>`*...*q`<sub>`m+1`</sub> is any other sequence of increasing primes. Since `p`<sub>`i`</sub>`<= q`<sub>`i`</sub> for `i = 1...m+1`, it follows that the product of the `q`'s must exceed `n`.

```
require 'prime'

def max_number_primes(n)
  return 0 if n < 2
  t = 1
  Prime.each_with_object([]) do |p, a|
    tmp = p*t
    return a if tmp > n
    a << p
    t = tmp
  end
end

max_number_primes(50)              #=> [2, 3, 5]
max_number_primes(50_000)          #=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13] 
max_number_primes(10_000_000_000)  #=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

Comment: I have said this many times already: Project Euler, HackerRank and whatever their names are *not* programming problems. If you use them to learn programming, you are doing it wrong. They are maths problems. They teach you maths, not programming. An answer to a Project Euler / HackerRank / etc. problem should usually involve a proof or at least some equations or mathematical arguments. This answer is a nice example of that. +1